# Apache POI : API to identify tables in the excel sheet and read them

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Is there any method which returns a list of tables present in the sheet?
My requirement is to fetch data from multiple tables present on the sheet.

Comment: That's quite a "human" operation you're asking for there. How do you define a separate table? Is it surrounded by a border? Is there a gap of 3 blank rows/cols since the last table? Some other characteristic? I think you'll need your own logic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume that you are using the `XSSF` API for `.xlsx` excel files.
If the tables were created by  `Insert->Table` then you can read them by using this :

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("test.xlsx"));
int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
for(int sheetIdx = 0; sheetIdx < numberOfSheets; sheetIdx++) {
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIdx);
    List<XSSFTable> tables = sheet.getTables();
    for(XSSFTable t : tables) {
        System.out.println(t.getDisplayName());
        System.out.println(t.getName());
        System.out.println(t.getNumerOfMappedColumns());
    }
}
```

If by `table` you mean anything that has a border then you have to create a non-trivial algorithm that reads all the cells of every sheet and checks the boundaries (e.g. `leftBorderColor`, `rightBorderColor`, `topBorderColor`, `bottomBorderColor`) and by defining what consists a `table` check if you've found it.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For all those who want to read tables from a java code, here is the working code.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("test.xlsx"));
    int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
    for (int sheetIdx = 0; sheetIdx < numberOfSheets; sheetIdx++) {
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIdx);
        List<XSSFTable> tables = sheet.getTables();
        for (XSSFTable t : tables) {
            System.out.println(t.getDisplayName());
            System.out.println(t.getName());
            System.out.println(t.getNumerOfMappedColumns());

            int startRow = t.getStartCellReference().getRow();
            int endRow = t.getEndCellReference().getRow();
            System.out.println("startRow = " + startRow);
            System.out.println("endRow = " + endRow);

            int startColumn = t.getStartCellReference().getCol();
            int endColumn = t.getEndCellReference().getCol();

            System.out.println("startColumn = " + startColumn);
            System.out.println("endColumn = " + endColumn);

            for (int i = startRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
                String cellVal = "";

                for (int j = startColumn; j <= endColumn; j++) {
                    XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(j);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        cellVal = cell.getStringCellValue();
                    }
                    System.out.print(cellVal + "\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }

    workbook.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this to use it with a Pojo class and annotations:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import com.madx.finance.data.utils.exels.read.ExelColumn;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        readExel(ExamplePojo.class);
    }

    public static class ExamplePojo  {
        public ExamplePojo(){}
        @ExelColumn(columnName="Column 1 String Name On Exel")
        protected String column1;
        @ExelColumn(columnName="Column 2 String Name On Exel")
        protected String column2;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> readExel(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        List<T> rows = new ArrayList<T>();
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new File("test.xlsx"));

        int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        for (int sheetIdx = 0; sheetIdx < numberOfSheets; sheetIdx++) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIdx);
            List<XSSFTable> tables = sheet.getTables();
            for (XSSFTable t : tables) {
                System.out.println(t.getDisplayName());
                System.out.println(t.getName());
                System.out.println(t.getNumerOfMappedColumns());

                int startRow = t.getStartCellReference().getRow();
                int endRow = t.getEndCellReference().getRow();
                System.out.println("startRow = " + startRow);
                System.out.println("endRow = " + endRow);

                int startColumn = t.getStartCellReference().getCol();
                int endColumn = t.getEndCellReference().getCol();

                System.out.println("startColumn = " + startColumn);
                System.out.println("endColumn = " + endColumn);

                // Loads all the annotated fields and builds a map for:
                // columnName, field
                List<Field> annotatedFields = FieldUtils.getFieldsListWithAnnotation(clazz, ExelColumn.class);
                Map<String, Field> annotatedFieldsMap = new HashMap<String, Field>();
                for (Field field : annotatedFields)
                    annotatedFieldsMap.put(field.getAnnotation(ExelColumn.class).columnName(), field);

                // Reads the used header names
                List<Pair<Integer, Field>> consideredColumns = new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Field>>();
                for (int j = startColumn; j <= endColumn; j++) {
                    XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(startRow).getCell(j);
                    if (cell != null) {
                        String columnName = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        Field field = annotatedFieldsMap.get(columnName);
                        if (field != null) {
                            Integer cellColumn = j;
                            Pair<Integer, Field> p = new ImmutablePair<Integer, Field>(cellColumn, field);
                            consideredColumns.add(p);
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (int i = startRow + 1; i <= endRow; i++) {
                    try {
                        T row = clazz.newInstance();
                        for (Pair<Integer, Field> pair : consideredColumns) {
                            XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(pair.getKey());
                            if (cell != null) {
                                Field field = pair.getValue();
                                field.setAccessible(true);
                                Class<?> fieldClass = field.getType();
                                if(Number.class.isAssignableFrom(fieldClass)){
                                    field.set(row, cell.getNumericCellValue());
                                } else {
                                    field.set(row, cell.getStringCellValue());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        rows.add(row);
                    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        workbook.close();
        return rows;
    }
}
```